# How can I translate the word 지룡전 into English? I am not able to find any translation in google

Tags: translation, korean-to-english

How do I translate 지룡전?
지룡 is being used a lot and used to a lot of sentences, but I can't find any good translation, google translated it as Earth Dragon. It is sometimes used as a name like 지룡님. I recently encountered it being used as 지룡전, 지룡께 and 지룡대. So how can I translate it correctly?

Additionaly, how do I translate 쌍룡, 서장밀교, 대막 살랑대 and 독수혈검?

Comment: 지룡 = Earth dragon / Wyrm or sometimes whatever dragonic creature from fictions and fantasy

Comment: You should mention the title of the book you are reading, at least. Most of them seem like its own terms. When the author of a martial arts novel introduces their own terms, they use Hanja (Chinese characters) along with Hangul for the reader to understand the meaning.

Comment: I'm currently reading 《지천명 아비무쌍》Jicheonmyeong Apimussang, most popularly known as Peerless Dad. The author does not really use Hanja that much.

Comment: The author uses Hanja for [지룡](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=iffqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT158&lpg=PT158#v=onepage&q&f=false), which is not 地龍 but 知龍. Someone translated it into [Wise Dragon](https://peerless-dad.fandom.com/wiki/Ji_Hakdo). Without Hanja, you may misinterpret those words.

Answer (score 1):

No one can answer this question correctly if no context is given.
지룡 probably means earth dragon where 지(地) is the earth and 룡(龍) is dragon.
지룡께 means 'to 지룡'. For example, '나는 지룡께 인사드렸다.' is 'I said hello to the earth dragon.'

Some comments said it is 'wise dragon' rather than 'earth dragon.' That might be true.

쌍룡 must mean double or twin dragons.

서장 is probably 西藏 which means Tibet in Chinese. 밀교 is 密敎 which is literally the secret religion. In the Buddhism context, please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vajrayana.

If 살랑대 is 殺狼隊, 殺 is to kill, 狼 is wolf, and 隊 is a group or army unit. So it becomes wolf hunting troops.